# Fancybox JS not resizing images

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox, image-resizing

Bundled with a purchased Fancy-Gallery plugin, Fancybox JS is not resizing images.

fancy-gallery.com

fancyapps.com/fancybox/

http://www.watercolorusahonorsociety.org/whsdev/index.php/test-gallery/

Last two images are resized manually as originals (1000px and 600px)

Wordpress version 4.2.4 using Divi Theme 2.4 (also tried the gallery w/o Divi Theme).

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: I checked your link. Images look like resized. I look into network tab and see 2 request for 1 image. What's for?

Comment: Hi ebilgin, thank you for the reply, much appreciated.
I've looked at the gallery using Chrome v. 44.0.2403.130 and Safari v. 7.0.6 on Mac OS 10.9.4 and they're not resizing. Interesting you say that they are for you. What are you using to view the gallery?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by '2 request for 1 image'

Comment: Actually 3. When you click the first image on your gallery. I can see 3 request on your server. You can see the images on chrome developer toolbar > network panel. Something wrong with your code and i don't know what it is. Image paths, http://www.watercolorusahonorsociety.org/whsdev/wp-content/fancygallery/3/6/beautiful_girl_30x40.jpg, http://www.watercolorusahonorsociety.org/whsdev/wp-content/fancygallery/3/6/beautiful_girl_30x40_300px_resized.jpg, http://www.watercolorusahonorsociety.org/whsdev/wp-content/fancygallery/3/6/beautiful_girl_30x40_resized.jpg

Comment: ebilgin, thank you so much for this. I'll see if I can find up what's up with the code.